# Make shapefiles based on a field of queries with ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy

Example table:

```
    qname   TheTableName SqlString
0   shp_q1  ER_AST_A     SELECT ...
1   shp_q2  ER_AST_B     SELECT ...
2   shp_q3  INT_AST_PX   SELECT ...
```

What are displayed in the `tablename` are polygon feaures in a geodatabase.
I would like for each row in a loop to take each `tablename` and apply the sql query in the `sqlstring` field and make the feature according to that query that corresponds.

What I tried:

```
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\05234\Proj.gdb"

datasetList = arcpy.ListTables("*")

for dataset in datasetList:
...      with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, ["TheTableName","SqlString"]) as cur:
...           for row in cur:
...               print(row)
```

This gives:

```
(ER_AST_A,query)
(ER_AST_B,query)     
(INT_AST_PX,query)
```

How can I proceed? Probably needs a select by attribute but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/299665/115

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm) functions to export the features to a new feature class or shapefile, just pass your sql query as the where_clause argument.